# Why gradlew assembleDebug doesn't run jetifier, while react-native run-android run jetifier?

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew, android-jetifier

I've set `android.useAndroidX = true` and `android.enableJetifier = true` on gradle.properties. But when I run `react-native run-android` I see:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1902 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
```

But when I change dir to android dir, and run `./gradlew assembleDebug`, I didn't see such thing. Hence my build breaks everywhere where there's `android.support.*` library imported.

```
> Task :react-native-app-auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
.../node_modules/react-native-app-auth/android/src/main/java/com/rnappauth/
RNAppAuthModule.java:10: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
.../node_modules/react-native-app-auth/android/src/main/java/com/rnappauth/RNAppAuthModule.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsCallback;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class CustomTabsCallback
  location: package android.support.customtabs
.../node_modules/react-native-app-auth/android/src/main/java/com/rnappauth/RNAppAuthModule.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class CustomTabsClient
  location: package android.support.customtabs

(25 more errors)
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this? Is there any way to externally force gradlew to run jetifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run

`npx jetify`

before assembleDebug

Comment: Interesting. This answer still benefits me as I use a script now to run through all the needed process to build APK, including the `react-native run-android`. Now I can replace the longer running time `react-native run-android` with the shorter running time `npx jetify`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer. So that your gradle build includes the jetifier-ed codes of your libraries, the step is simple.

1. Run `react-native run-android` first. This will jetifier the libraries and put them in the build folder.
2. Run `./gradlew assembleDebug`. This will grab your jetifier-ed code in the build folder into APK without complaining anymore.

My case is that I run `./gradlew assembleDebug` before I ever run `react-native run-android` after I clone the project. Deleting build folder in android folder also resulting the same situation.

Comment: I find `react-native run-android` run transforms first while the android generate apk steps doesnt include this step. Is there any working solution other. than this?

Comment: @heisenberg by running the `react-native run-android` first, then run android generate apk, the android generate apk will automatically include what's already in the build folder, including the jetified libraries.